# Find the row/column with the lowest maxima

Tags: matlab, octave

Consider the matrix below:

```
A = randi([0 100], 5, 7)
```

---

```
62   59   20   42   49   41   83
37   34   13   65   82   47   24
93   33   19   93   30   37   20
42   49   74   96   26   41   21
14   85   14   90   77    4   96
```

first I want to find the maxima of each row and the column index:

```
   83    7
   82    5
   93    1
   96    4
   96    7
```

then I need to find the row with the lowest maxima:

```
82 5 2
```

so far, I have implemented this:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

A = randi([0 100], 5, 7);

[M1, I1] = max(A, [], 2);

[M1, I1]

[M2, I2] = min(M1);

[M2, I1(I2), I2]
```

Though it feels like a workaround, I wondered if there is a more canonical way to do this? Maybe a built-in function or `min`/`max` syntax for this specific purpose?

**P.S.** Shared this question also on the [MATLAB Discord channel](https://discord.com/channels/384316553497280512/754701275735654410/816938551493001236).

Comment: I don't understand how your second output is `47` - the min of your example `M1` is surely `82`?

Comment: @Wolfie thanks. It was a random generation issue. I forgot to edit the old values out.

Comment: I'd say this is the best you can do but that could be opinion-based. What exactly is dirty in your solution?

Comment: Do you need to store `M1` and `I1` as outputs, or are you just using them as intermediates? `min` and `max` are pretty quick at achieving what you're doing, I doubt you're going to find anything more elegant or performant than one call to each of these

Comment: @Wolfie no I don't need `M1` and `I1`. Can I eliminate them?

Comment: No, I don't think so, I'm with Thomas - it's unclear to me what you think is "dirty" about this solution. I was just asking to clarify in case there was some way to do this in one step. I suspect if there is it will be less readable and slower.

Comment: @Wolfie Maybe I should ask the question the other way. How would you do it if you hadn't seen the code block above? can you think of alternative ways that are cleaner / faster?

Comment: @LuisMendo no I also need the position of that min max

Comment: @Foad Sorry, I misunderstood a previous comment of yours. Then I agree with Wolfie and Thomas Sablik: I don’t think it can be done more succinctly or elegantly

Answer (score 2):

What about this with `find`?

```
M = min(max(A,[],2));
[i,j] = find(A == M);
[M,j,i]
```